# How do I make dua for thunderstorm to come

Tags: quran

well I want to know if there dua for thunderstorm to come or I will find the dua myself pls answer pls tell me. I tried finding it first time but nope.

Comment: You can pray for rain, but why would you pray for a thunderstorm?

Comment: Because I love thunderstorm it has heavy rain and thunder

Comment: Why should a Muslim which something bad for himself and others? Thunderstorms are dangerous

Comment: Although you may make dua that dua is not guaranteed to be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You should always pray for rain that is **beneficial** for all

> اللّهُمَّ اَسْقِـنا غَيْـثاً مُغيـثاً مَريئاً مُريـعاً، نافِعـاً
>   غَيْـرَ ضَّارٌ، عاجِـلاً غَـيْرَ آجِلٍ
>
> Allaahumma 'asqinaa ghaythan mugheethan maree'an maree'an, naafi'an
>   ghayradhaarrin, 'aajilan ghayra 'aajilin.
>
> O Allah, shower upon us abundant rain, beneficial not harmful, swiftly
>   and not delayed.
>
> Abu Dawud 1:303

But fyi, there is a dua when it thunders too

> سُبْـحانَ الّذي يُسَبِّـحُ الـرَّعْدُ بِحَمْـدِهِ، وَالملائِكـةُ مِنْ
>   خيـفَته
>
> Subhaanal-lathee yusabbihur-ra'du bihamdihi walmalaa'ikatu min
>   kheefatihi.
>
> Glory is to Him Whom thunder and angels glorify due to fear of Him.